# Add ArrayList to another ArrayList dynamically is treading values

Tags: java, android, json, for-loop

```
{
   "clientes":[
      {
         "codigo":"1341",
         "empresa":0,
         "nombre":"asd",
         "e_mail":"cli@cli.com"
      },
      {
         "codigo":"5435",
         "empresa":0,
         "nombre":"asd",
         "e_mail":"cli@cli.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to extract the keys and values from a json then in an array I put all the keys and in another array all the values. The problem now is that more than 1 client can come, so I have to make a list of arrays of keys, and a list of arrays of values

As you can see, in the output the values of position [0] are stepped on with that of position [1] and it shouldn't be like that, because in the "codigo" field I send different values ..

```
ArrayList listArrayKeys = new ArrayList();
ArrayList listArrayValues = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> arrayKeys = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arrayValues = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
JSONObject jsonObject;
String tableName;

void getKeysAndValues() throws JSONException {
try {
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        System.out.println(key);
        if(jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(key);
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                Iterator<String> innerKeys = object.keys();
                arrayValues.clear();
                while(innerKeys.hasNext()) {
                    String innerKey = innerKeys.next();
                    String innerValue = object.getString(innerKey);
                    arrayKeys.add(innerKey);
                    arrayValues.add(innerValue);
                    System.out.println(innerKey);
                }
                listArrayKeys.add(arrayKeys);
                listArrayValues.add(arrayValues);
            }
            Log.d("ARRAYVALUES", String.valueOf(listArrayValues));
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

output:

```
[[5435, 0, asd, cli@cli.com], [5435, 0, asd, cli@cli.com]
```

should be:

```
[[1341, 0, asd, cli@cli.com], [5435, 0, asd, cli@cli.com]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of replace array.clear() with a new array. this way, you'll be adding keys to two arrays as desired

```
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        System.out.println(key);
        if(jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(key);
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                Iterator<String> innerKeys = object.keys();
//                arrayValues.clear();
                arrayValues = new ArrayList<>();
                while(innerKeys.hasNext()) {
                    String innerKey = innerKeys.next();
                    String innerValue = object.getString(innerKey);
                    arrayKeys.add(innerKey);
                    arrayValues.add(innerValue);
                    System.out.println(innerKey);
                }
                listArrayKeys.add(arrayKeys);
                listArrayValues.add(arrayValues);
            }
            Log.d("ARRAYVALUES", String.valueOf(listArrayValues));
        }
    }
```

Comment: And that was all! I am a trainee programmer and in real practice, you need other people (like you) who know and tell you SPECIFICALLY what was causing problems, because I spent hours trying and did not know that that was the error. Thank you!